# Overloading "new" and "delete" operator with extra parameters depending on configuration

Tags: c++

I am working on a game engine and I have some troubles overloading the new and delete operators.

The reason for overloading the operators is because I want to be able to show some metrics about allocations/deallocations in the game engine GUI. In order to be able to show the user where the allocations are comming from either the engine or the game. This because the user is not interested in allocations made by the engine_gui (that wont be in his game build) but he might be interested in allocations made in the engine or the game itself in order to make decisions about API usage of the engine or scripting of the game.

The project structure is something like this:

- Engine(.dll) contains declaration of overloads and macro
- EngineGUI(.exe) implements Engine.dll and Game.dll
- Game(.dll/.exe) implements Engine.dll

I overloaded the "new" operator with the following:

```cpp
#ifdef DEBUG
#define NEW(size, isEngine) new(size_t size, bool isEngine)

// use in engine and engine GUI
void* operator new(size_t size, bool isEngine)
{
    if (isEngine)
    {
        cheetah::MemoryMetrics::addMemoryAllocatedEngine(size);
    }
    return malloc(size);
}

// use in game
void* operator new(size_t size)
{

    cheetah::MemoryMetrics::addMemoryAllocatedGame(size);
    return malloc(size);
}

#else 
#define NEW(size, isEngine) new(size_t size)
#endif // DEBUG
```

The reason for having 2 overloads is to make it easier to use while developing a game, no need to pass in some enum to specify the location.

Now I ran in the following issues:

- Delete can't be overloaded with extra parameters and so I have no way of knowing where the delete is called from either engine or game(at least as far as I know)
- The boolean "isGame" would also need to be passed in production code, something I dont really want so I defined a macro(NEW), that depending on environment should replace with the right "new" overload but I can't get the macro to work.

I have tried using the new Macro like this:

```cpp
BatchData* s_data = NEW(true) BatchData();
```

**results in:**

> expected an expression

and this:

```cpp
BatchData* s_data = NEW(sizeof(BatchData), true) BatchData();
```

**results in:**

> expected a ')'

**My questions**

- What is the right syntax for the NEW macro(if it is even possible).
- How could I get the caller of the delete function(Engine, EngineGUI or Game) be known when calling 
  delete.
- Is this the right way(overloading/macros) or are there better solutions(I don't realy like using macros).

Comment: You should learn how to overload the memory allocation function `operator new`, and how to use placement new before embarking on any macros. Look at some examples and you will not find anything resembling `Type* t = new (size_t sizeof(BatchData), bool true) Type;`.

Comment: You also need to study how new-expressions relate to, but are different from, allocation functions. (This is a much too large subject for an SO question and answer.)

Comment: I suggest you focus your question on one issue. Currently you are asking about multiple ones (how to use the operator new, how to know the boolean on deallocation, etc.). Also start with the simple case. What you are showing should already fail if you just replace default global allocation/deallocation functions to always log.